# Suggested Method to Forward POST Parameters Through login_required Decorator?

Tags: django, django-forms

I am currently having the problem that when I use the login_required decorator from django.contrib.auth.decorators on any of my views, my POST parameters do not arrive at the protected view whenever the decorator did redirect (to the login page) and back again to the protected view.  Suggestions about how to work around this (preferably maintaining the convenience of the login_required decorator and the POST method) appreciated!

[This page](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/849) appears to be a contested Django ticket about the matter.  Although the bug/enhancement was framed in terms of template vs. view logic instead of just making parameters accessible to a view, which is my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have developed the following solution using sessions that I find acceptable.  Dealing with redirects and substituting views is tricky, and this method seems to be the best balance of not fiddling with the framework and not fighting the HTTP protocol while gaining the desired functionality.  The negative aspect of this method is the extra work required in each protected view checking the session variables.

1. Create a custom decorator (`login_required2`, below) that returns the requested view if the user is authenticated and the project's login view otherwise.
2. The login view:

   1. Stores the original `POST` parameters in a session variable.
   2. Stores the original `HTTP_REFERER` in a session variable
   3. If the user correctly authenticates, returns the view corresponding to the requested path (the requested path remains identical throughout the login process, and is identical to the path the user requested when they were originally passed the login view instead.)
3. Any views protected thus must check the session variables before they use either the request's `POST` or `META['HTTP_REFERER']`

Code follows:

```
def login_view(request):    
    from django.conf import settings
    from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve

    USERNAME_FIELD_KEY = 'username'
    PASSWORD_FIELD_KEY = 'password'

    message = '' #A message to display to the user
    error_message = '' #An error message to display to the user

    #If the request's path is not the login URL, the user did not explicitly request 
    # the login page and we assume this view is protecting another.
    protecting_a_view = request.path != settings.LOGIN_URL

    post_params_present = bool(request.POST)

    #Any POST with username and password is considered a login attempt, regardless off what other POST parameters there may be
    login_attempt = request.POST and request.POST.has_key(USERNAME_FIELD_KEY) and request.POST.has_key(PASSWORD_FIELD_KEY)

    if protecting_a_view:
        message = 'You must login for access.'
        if not request.session.has_key(ACTUAL_REFERER_KEY):
            #Store the HTTP_REFERER if not already
            request.session[ACTUAL_REFERER_KEY] = request.META.get(HTTP_REFERER_KEY)

    if protecting_a_view and post_params_present and not login_attempt: 
        #Store the POST parameters for the protected view
        request.session[FORWARDED_POST_PARAMS_KEY] = request.POST

    if login_attempt:
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data[USERNAME_FIELD_KEY]
            password = form.cleaned_data[PASSWORD_FIELD_KEY]
            user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    auth.login(request, user)
                    if protecting_a_view:
                        actual_view, actual_args, actual_kwargs = resolve(request.path) #request.path refers to the protected view
                        return actual_view(request, *actual_args, **actual_kwargs)
                    else:
                        HttpResponseRedirect('/')
                else:
                    message = 'That account is inactive.'
            else:
                error_message = 'That username or password is incorrect.'
    else:
        form = LoginForm()

    context_dict = {
        'form': form,
        'message': message,
        'error_message': error_message,
    }
    return render_to_response2('my_app/login.html', context_dict)

@login_required2
def protected_view(request):
    post_params = {}

    if request.POST:
        post_params = request.POST
    elif request.session.has_key(FORWARDED_POST_PARAMS_KEY):
        post_params = request.session[FORWARDED_POST_PARAMS_KEY]
        del request.session[FORWARDED_POST_PARAMS_KEY]
    if post_params:
        #Process post_params as if it were request.POST here:
        pass

    #assuming this view ends with a redirect.  Otherwise could render view normally
    if request.session.has_key(ACTUAL_REFERER_KEY):
        redirect_location = request.session.get(ACTUAL_REFERER_KEY)
    elif request.META.get(HTTP_REFERER_KEY) != request.path:
        redirect_location = request.META.get(HTTP_REFERER_KEY)
    else:
        redirect_location = ROOT_PATH
    return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_location)

def login_required2(view_func):
    """
    A decorator that checks if the request has an authenticated user.
    If so it passes the request to the view.
    Otherwise, it passes the request to the login view, which is responsible
    for recognizing that the request was originally for another page and forwarding
    state along (GET, POST).

    See django.contrib.auth.decorators for how Django's auth decorators mesh 
    using _CheckLogin.  This decorator bypasses that for my ease of creation.
    """
    def login_required_decoration(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            from django.conf import settings
            from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve

            login_url = settings.LOGIN_URL
            login_view, login_args, login_kwargs = resolve(login_url)
            #Here the user gets a login view instad of the view they requested
            return login_view(request, *login_args, **login_kwargs)
    return login_required_decoration
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no easy way to do this, not to mention the fact that you want to use the "login_required" decorator. You can do your own view that checks for the is_authenticated method and does the right thing, like serializing the POST data and passing around, but this is very error prone.

The easy workaround is to change your form to do GET instead of POST.

Comment: What's right/wrong with a solution like having @login_required passing all POST parameters to the protected view?  Isn't that relatively straightforward to implement?

Comment: It's a "two phase process". First you have to store the POST parameters somewhere while the user is entering his login information in the login view. After that, you'll have to check the user login/passowrd, login the user and the do another post to the right view(the first one).

Comment: I guess those two phases seem pretty common-sense to me, but admittedly I'm not writing the backend so..thanks for cluing me in.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty old question but the need still exists today.

Based on the hints provided in previous answers, I made the following mixin for class-based views:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse, urlencode

from django.http import QueryDict, HttpRequest
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import AccessMixin

class loginRequiredOnPostMixin (AccessMixin):
    """
    Lets a CBV be freely accessible on GET requests, but requires login on POST.
    On redirect for unauthenticated POST requests, the POST parameters are stored in the session.
    Once the user authenticated and is redirected to the page as GET, the POST parameters are retrieved so the request can complete.
    """
    SESSION_REFERER_KEY = None
    SESSION_POST_PARAMS_KEY = None

    def get_session_referer_key(self):
        return self.SESSION_REFERER_KEY or 'POST_REDIRECT_REFERER'

    def get_session_post_params_key(self):
        return self.SESSION_POST_PARAMS_KEY or 'POST_PARAMS'

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        referer_key = self.get_session_referer_key()
        post_params_key = self.get_session_post_params_key()

        if request.method == 'POST' and bool(request.POST) and not request.user.is_authenticated:
            # save the referer url to match it later in case of GET to the same page (after login)
            if not request.session.has_key(referer_key): # so we don't overwrite previous values)
                parsed_url = urlparse(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
                request.session[referer_key] = parsed_url.path
                # save the POST params in the session
                request.session[post_params_key] = request.POST
            #redirect to login View
            return self.handle_no_permission()

        elif request.method == 'POST' and request.user.is_authenticated:
            # user logged in and rePOSTed... clean up and let the magic work on its on
            if request.session.has_key(referer_key):
                del request.session[referer_key]
            if request.session.has_key(post_params_key):
                del request.session[post_params_key]

        elif request.method == 'GET' and request.user.is_authenticated:
            print ("dispatch: GET authenticated")
            if request.session.has_key(referer_key):
                if request.session[referer_key] == request.get_full_path():
                    newRequest = HttpRequest()
                    newRequest.COOKIES = request.COOKIES
                    newRequest.META = request.META
                    newRequest.FILES = request.FILES
                    newRequest.path = request.path
                    newRequest.path_info = request.path_info
                    newRequest.method = 'POST'
                    newRequest.resolver_match = request.resolver_match
                    newRequest.content_type = request.content_type
                    newRequest.content_params = request.content_params
                    q = QueryDict(urlencode(request.session[post_params_key]))
                    newRequest.POST = q
                    newRequest.session = request.session
                    newRequest.user = request.user
                    self.request = newRequest
                    del request.session[referer_key]
                    del request.session[post_params_key]
                    return super().dispatch(newRequest, *args, **kwargs)
                # we clean up as it seems the user has moved on.
                del request.session[referer_key]
                del request.session[post_params_key]
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Following a successful login, it actually recreates the HttpRequest object and turns it into a POST request, before calling `super().dispatch(...)`

If used in a `FormView`, make sure to recreate the form with the adequate POST data, as such:

```
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Works for me.
Enjoy!