# decorating a view with @login_required makes POST requests fail

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm trying to handle a POST request from outside of django to path `/app/process`
When I decorate my view with `@login_required` the requests come to my view change to `/app/process/login?next=/app/process/` and `request.POST` contains non of my posted data!

What is the problem?

My View is like this:

```
@login_required
def callback(request):
    state = request.POST['State']
```

**EDIT:**
If i log `request.user` in view user is there so he is actually loggedin!

Comment: how are you making the post request?

Comment: @ruddra: There is a form in another domain (it is Bank payment callback) which its action is my path

Comment: That is the purpose of the decorator: if you are not logged in you will be redirected to the login form. Did you expect something else?

Comment: @KlausD: actually user is logged in; the proccess is: user logins in django then he is redirected to another website which redirects him back to django callback url after its job finished. so user has the session cookie and must be logged in

Comment: does it show `True` for `request.user.is_authenticated`? @RYN

Comment: @ruddra: with `@login_require` yes; and without it, no

Answer (score 0):

The error should be with the session. The `@login_required` decorator indicates that all the requests to the view function should be authenticated. So check whether your session object holding the logged user data or not.

just try..

```
request.POST.get('State')
```

this may work I guess..

please refer this question too,
[Suggested Method to Forward POST Parameters Through login_required Decorator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563819/suggested-method-to-forward-post-parameters-through-login-required-decorator)

Comment: But user is logged in !  when i get `request.user` before POST['State']  user is there!