# Django - @login_required decorator while passing arguments with form POST

Tags: django, django-views, django-login, login-required

I am passing a variable from template to view with form POST method. And view uses @login_required decorator as it is needed. If user is not logged in it goes login page and come backs to the view again but the passed variable information was not there anymore. Is there any way to solve this? I found a old stackoverflow post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563819/suggested-method-to-forward-post-parameters-through-login-required-decorator) but it's not working for me. Below is my view function

```
@login_required
def become_booster(request):
    if request.method == "POST" 
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        user = CustomUser.objects.get(email= email)
        tiers = Tiers.objects.filter(user=user)
        form = SubscriptionForm
        return render(request,'select_tier.html',{'tiers':tiers,'form':form,'creator':user})
```

Comment: Not sure why you're using POST here in the first place. That's for creating and updating data; here you're using the values to filter, so it should be a GET.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It's working now. Instead of form POST, I am sending user info with url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of form POST, I am sending user info with url and my issue was resolved.

```
@login_required
def become_booster(request,email):
    user = CustomUser.objects.get(email= email)
    tiers = Tiers.objects.filter(user=user)
    form = SubscriptionForm
    return render(request,'select_tier.html',{'tiers':tiers,'form':form,'creator':user})
```